# Set width of igx-select

Tags: html, infragistics, ignite-ui

I have multiple `igx-selects` that are used to display a drop-down list.

I want to change the width of this particular `igx-select` (not for all `igx-selects` that I have) as well as the font-size of the list. As I tried nothing worked. Is this possible in SCSS?

Here is my `igx-select` block.

```
  <igx-select #selectCity
              placeholder="Select city"
              [overlaySettings]="overlaySettings"
              [(ngModel)]="city" name="cities">
      <igx-select-item style="width: 430px" *ngFor="let item of cities" [value]="item">
          {{ item }}
      </igx-select-item>
  </igx-select>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

IgxSelect's width depends on the width of its parent container. If you want to change the width of igxSelect you should set the width of its parent like this:

```
<div style="width: 430px">
  <igx-select #selectCity
              placeholder="Select city"
              [overlaySettings]="overlaySettings"
              [(ngModel)]="city" name="cities">
      <igx-select-item *ngFor="let item of cities" [value]="item">
          {{ item }}
      </igx-select-item>
  </igx-select>
```

If you need to set the width of the select's dropdown this is a little more tricky. One way to achieve this is to handle `opening` event of the select. In the handler you can set the width of the select toggle element, this is the dropdown, like this:

```
public selectOpening(evt: IBaseCancelableBrowserEventArgs) {
   evt.owner.toggleDirective.element.style.width = "430px";
}
```

Keep in mind this may brake the positioning of the select dropdown. Setting of the font of the select items could be done via CSS applied to the item itself like this:

```
  <igx-select #selectCity
              placeholder="Select city"
              [overlaySettings]="overlaySettings"
              [(ngModel)]="city" name="cities">
      <igx-select-item style="font-size: 15px;" *ngFor="let item of cities" [value]="item">
          {{ item }}
      </igx-select-item>
  </igx-select>
```

Again this may break the positioning of the select items. One way to set the size of the items is via `DisplsyDensity`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I use igx-select in a column of a grid. Is it possible to adjust the width of the igx-select, as I tried the examples that you gave me, nothing has changed. I think that the igx-select has a default max width, that I am trying to change.

The other igx-select is inside an igx-dialog and the examples are not working also. Could you please help me? Thank you very much again!